# Reaching FTP Port Through Domain Name

Tags: browser, ftp, portforwarding

I have a domain name which is a bit private (which I will be calling it "foo.org" -Ne offense- ). This domain is now pointing at my router's external ip. And port 80 is forwarded to a computer with website codes on it. When domain name is entered to a browser, router redirects client to this computer properly. Though, ı also have a computer with ftp server on it, and routers port 21 is forwarded to this computer. Assuming my external ip is: 84.178.34.26, when I write 'ftp://84.178.34.26', browser redirects me properly but result changes if I search for: 'ftp://foo.org'. Browser keeps loading for ages and eventually returns: "Could not connect". I've been trying to fix this for months. Pls help and excuse my inexperience...

Answer (score 0):

Something i forgot to mention causes this: Cloudflare. Since it doesn't support ftp, unless you deactivate proxy (unless you make the orange cloud turn grey in dns settings.) you won't be able to reach your ftp server.